# Выравнивание всплывающей ul по центру относительно родителя

Tags: css, css3

Здравствуйте, есть код меню со сплывающими окнами , как можно сделать так,чтоб всплывающие `ul` были посередине родительского `li`?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#track-nav {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#track-nav li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: block;
}

.track-nav-menu {
  display: inline-block;
}

#track-nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.25s linear opacity;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

#track-nav ul li {
  float: none;
}

#track-nav ul a {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
}

#track-nav li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#track-nav li:hover ul li {
  padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
}

#track-nav li:hover ul:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 35px;
  border-width: 0 6px 6px 6px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fff transparent;
}

#track-nav li:hover ul:before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  right: 13px;
  border-width: 0 8px 8px 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
}

#track-nav li:hover a {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.clearfix_track:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

#track-nav li:hover ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.075s linear;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="track" class="container">
    <nav class="nav-menu">
      <ul id="track-nav" class="clearfix_track">
        <li>
          <a href="/">Главная</a>
          <span>&gt;&gt;</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class="consum"> <a class="consum" href="/product/catalog">Материалы</a></span>
          <span>&gt;&gt;</span>
          <ul>
            <li>Первый gdgsfgs dfghdsfh</li>
            <li>Второй</li>
            <li>Третий</li>
            <li>Четвертый</li>
            <li>Пятый</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/zhestkie-listovye-materialy">Цветные карандаши</a>
          <ul>
            <li>Вспененные ПВХ листы</li>
            <li>Красный dfdfd</li>
            <li>Зеленый dfdfd</li>
            <li>Синий dfdf</li>
          </ul>
          <span>&gt;&gt;</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/listovoi-pvh">Бумага цветная</a>
          <span>&gt;&gt;</span>
          <ul>
            <li>fdfd</li>
            <li>dfdf</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если, кому-то интересно ,вопрос решился путем добавления в родительский `li` `position:relative`, так же добавлением в

```
#track-nav ul {
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Так же, такую же процедуру проводим для

```
#track-nav li:hover ul:after
```